# Ruby Post Request with Basic Auth and Multiple data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm using RestClient gem, below is my command

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Basic ENCODED_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS' --data 'username=user@test.com&password=test&grant_type=password&scope=user%20documents%20user%2Fdocumentsv2' https://api.com/oauth2/token
```

I'm don't translating this via `RestClient` below is my code:

```
access = RestClient::Request.new(
        :method => :post,
        :url => 'https://api.com/oauth2/token',
        :data => {
            :username => 'xxxx',
            :password => 'xxxx',
            :grant_type => 'password'
        },
        :headers => {
            :Authorization => "Basic some_string",
            :'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    )
```

Showing 400 bad request.
Can anyone help for this translating.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrong on this line below

```
:data => {
   :username => 'xxxx',
   :password => 'xxxx',
   :grant_type => 'password'
},
```

You can use `payload` instead of `data` like below:

```
:payload => {
   :username => 'xxxx',
   :password => 'xxxx',
   :grant_type => 'password'
},
```

I hope help you.